# Snapshot in the fragment is returning empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create recycler view in fragment this class is fragment class.But snapshot is returning empty.I'm using same code for getting data( getPostSelf() ) in another class.It is working.So getting data code( getPostSelf() ) is true.

```
class PostListFragment() : Fragment() {

    var user_mail="example@example.com"
    var postList =ArrayList<Posts>()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPostListBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerAdapter

    private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=FragmentPostListBinding.inflate(requireActivity().layoutInflater)
        firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        getPostSelf()
        
        for(i in postList){
            println(i.postLabel)
        }
        //postList is empty because snapshot is empty 

        recyclerViewAdapter= RecyclerAdapter(postList)
        val layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager=layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter=recyclerViewAdapter
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_list, container, false)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun getPostSelf() {

        //Buraya Firestore dan kullanıcıya ait postları çekeceğiz.

        firestore.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("post_mail", user_mail)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
                if (exception != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "deeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                     println("Snapshot control : "+snapshot?.isEmpty())
                     // Logcat screen is giving "Snapshot control : true"
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                            var documents = snapshot.documents
                            postList.clear()

                            for (document in documents) {
                                var postObject = Posts(user_mail)
                                postObject.postLabel = document.get("post_label") as String
                                postObject.postDesc = document.get("post_desc") as String
                                postObject.postTime = document.get("post_time") as String
                                postObject.postFullName = document.get("post_FullName") as String
                                postList.add(postObject)
                                println(postObject.postLabel)
                            }
                            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                        }


                    }

                }
            }
    }

    }
```

I tried this function in the activity where the fragment is located.It isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_mail is an empty string. I think because of it, there is no matching item that has post_mail equal to "".

Another problem is the view is created in a wrong place. It should be create in onCreateView.

```
class PostListFragment() : Fragment() {
    var user_mail = ""
    var postList = ArrayList<Posts>()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPostListBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerAdapter

    private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        getPostSelf()
        
        for(i in postList){
            println(i.postLabel)
        }
        // postList is empty because snapshot is empty
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        getPostSelf()

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentPostListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(postList)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter

        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun getPostSelf() {
        //Buraya Firestore dan kullanıcıya ait postları çekeceğiz.
        firestore.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("post_mail", user_mail)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
                if (exception != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "deeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                     println("Snapshot control : " + snapshot?.isEmpty())
                     // Logcat screen is giving "Snapshot control : true"
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {
                            var documents = snapshot.documents
                            postList.clear()

                            for (document in documents) {
                                var postObject = Posts(user_mail)
                                postObject.postLabel = document.get("post_label") as String
                                postObject.postDesc = document.get("post_desc") as String
                                postObject.postTime = document.get("post_time") as String
                                postObject.postFullName = document.get("post_FullName") as String
                                postList.add(postObject)
                                println(postObject.postLabel)
                            }
                            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: .I filled user_mail manually but it didn't work.Can you explain more about view problem?Maybe I have a view problem

Comment: @gkhn.akbs onCreateView returns newly inflated view, it should return your `binding.root` view. I added the code to my answer.